# Restrict tick labels in matplotlib to 2 significant digits

Tags: python, matplotlib

I find `matplotlib` to be a great package, however the default settings are often pretty terrible. In this case I would like to force the numerical axis format to only show tick labels with a maximum of two significant figures. For small numbers I would like it to switch to scientific notation. Some examples:

0.000012 should show up on the ticklabels as 1.2E-5

50.5 should not show up on the ticklabels

5.5 should show up as 5.5

50 should show up as 50

So far I have tried

```
from matplotlib.ticker import FormatStrFormatter
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.2f'))
```

which truncates values when the tick is below 0.01. Furthermore it actually increases the number of shown digits when I have an integer. For example 50 shows up as 50.00.

Comment: Is this a single plot, which has `0.000012` as well as `50` as ticks? For the general case this requirement is rather cumbersome to implement, but for any specific plot it should be pretty straight forward.

Comment: I see the question not having changed after my first comment 2 days ago. This comment was of course meant to reflect what exactly is needed here and to [edit] the question accordingly. Also see [ask] and [mcve].